# Google Tag Manager is not recording the clicks in preview mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have created an eCommerce website using "Magento" platform & we've implemented the GTM container code as well.

But when in turn on preview mode and click on any button, the click is not getting recorded in the GTM preview mode summary section.

We have enabled all the predefined click variables still we are facing this issue.

Comment: Sometimes this happens, try to publish & reopen the preview mode, it should start working.

Comment: Make sure you have not re-initialised dataLayer variable `dataLayer =[]` by yourself. It must be there within the GTM container snippet. If you do that, GTM wont listen to anything